# Does the daily reputation cap slow down the growth of private betas?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit, private-beta

In private beta, the aim is to quickly get many good answers and good questions.

Does the daily reputation limit hinder this? If I'm at my limit, I might choose to wait until tomorrow to post more good questions and answers.

Comment: I don't exactly frequent the private betas that much but is it really that easy to hit the reputation cap there?

Comment: I've just hit it for the first time ever, and that was on (currently private β) [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 8):

There's more to a private beta than just generating a lot of questions and answers. Another aspect of it is to attract active users. If you hit the rep cap and decide to hold off till tomorrow to post something (though you shouldn't :)), that gives others a chance to contribute instead.

So it all balances out in the end.

That said, it's rare for someone to *consistently* hit the rep cap day after day during a private beta. If that happens, that would suggest to me that something's possibly a bit unusual on that site. For example, either the questions and answers are too obvious, or maybe there is a user who's "carrying" the site. It's not necessarily a sign that something's horribly wrong, but it'd draw my attention.

Comment: I'd also say that during the early days of beta (and especially during private beta), users are also much more generous when it comes to handing out upvotes. Not having a reputation cap would cause a very great unfair advantage for users who participated in beta.

Comment: @animuson and aside from plain generosity, it's just easier to keep up with and vote on all new questions and answers in the early days of a site.